# How many swarms of centipedes can I fit in a 40 gallon barrel?

Tags: dnd-5e, swarm

I'm playing in D&D 5e. I want to buy barrels of centipedes in Chult. How many swarms can I get per 40 gallon barrel?

Given a 40 gallon barrel, and a 5x5 (medium sized) swarm of centipedes, how many swarms fit in a single barrel?

Comment: Do you want a barrel of *live* centipedes?  Or just dead bugs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The rules don't say.  Ask your DM.

### But we can do some math, in case that helps.

Forty gallons appears to be 5.34 cubic feet.  A swarm of centipedes is Medium size, which means it normally occupies 25 *square* feet but the rules don't say to what height.

If the swarm was only two inches tall, then it would occupy a volume of 25/6 = 4.16 cubic feet, and thus could fit in the barrel, assuming that the centipedes on the bottom could survive the weight.

(I'm not sure if the centipedes on the bottom *could* survive that weight.)

If the swarm was three inches tall, then it would occupy a volume of 25/4 = 6.35 cubic feet and so it could not fit in the barrel.

Comment: Do note that the an average human fills 25 cubic feet to a depth of approximately 1.5 inches,

Comment: @fectin let's not visualize that, though xD

Comment: :D Agreed! Point is that depth of fill in a five-foot square may not be the most intuitive or useful measure.

Comment: I'd like to add the caveat that a Medium creature does not necessarily *occupy* a 5x5 ft square, but rather *controls* it. The swarm might be substantially smaller than 5x5 feet when splayed out.